# How do you retrieve or modify file timestamps on a recently downloaded file using NSFileManager?

Tags: ios

I have the following situation. A file has just been downloaded using an `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` and this returns a URL to the temporary file (`srcURL`) that has just been downloaded. I then move the file from the temporary URL to a new location in the sandbox caches directory (`dstURL`). This is done using the following;

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(srcURL, toURL: dstURL)
```

This appears to function without issue and no error is thrown when copying the item. It has been confirmed to exist and be available on the filesystem.

When I execute:

```
let attrs = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(dstURL.path!)
```

The `attrs` dictionary never contains the `NSFileCreationDate` and the `NSFileModificationDate` Even after reading if I reset it with the HTML. When I try to set the created at and updated at timestamps then scan the beacon classes people want to take.

Have I missed anything out in connection to how I should be using `NSFileManager`?

I have tested this out on both a simulator and a physical device with the same outcome data.

Comment: FYI - `copyItemAtURL` doesn't move the file, it copies the file. If you want to actually move the file (which you should), use `moveItemAtURL`.

Comment: Thanks I did mean move it must be getting late, updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to use [attributesOfItemAtPath(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:). There is no `NSFileCreationDate` for `attributesOfFileSystemForPath`

Comment: Thank you! That makes complete sense. I should have paid closer attention to the docs, and less blind faith in the autocomplete.

Comment: Haha happens to the best of us